# Using custom styles defined in Excel with openxyl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

With **openpyxl**, you can use [built-in styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#using-builtin-styles) defined in Excel like such:

```
wb = load_workbook("My_Template.xlsx")
ws = wb["My_super_Worksheet"]

ws["B2"].value = '=Hyperlink("https://stackoverflow.com", "SO")'
ws["B2"].style = "Hyperlink"
```

However, how would you use custom-styles defined in the Excel file? Something that could look like that:

```
wb = load_workbook("My_Template.xlsx")
ws = wb["My_super_Worksheet"]

wb.register_style("My_Custome_style")  # defined as custom style in My_Template.xlsx

ws["B2"].value = '=Hyperlink("https://stackoverflow.com", "SO")'
ws["B2"].style = ""My_Custome_style""
```

The only way I have found was to re-define the styles in your program as [Named Styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html#named-styles) and save it but this would involve defining again the style instead of re-using what already exists.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *"built-in styles defined in Excel"*: I think, wrong conclusion, as `built-in` means predefined in `openpyxl` **not** in a workbook. Probably these style shadows Excel built-ins.

Comment: openpyxl should read the named styles in an existing workbook so you should be able to use them without additional registration.

Comment: @CharlieClark It would be nice indeed. Should I add a request for enhancement or there is a secret way to do it?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. would a solution that uses pywin32 to open excel files be useful?

Comment: @EliyArlev Interesting idea. The drawback I see to your solution is having to open the files with `pywin32` (and maybe closing it) before processing with `openpyxl` (and the incompatibility on non-Windows OS).

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. I agree those are exactly the two main drawbacks. All styles are stored in an "Styles" object that every "Workbook" object has (the object that wraps an excel file). I can't assist you however with the "how are those objects represented in the openxyl framework"

Comment: @EliyArlev  This ` Styles` object is part of `pywin32` or `openpyxl`?

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT., it is accessible via pywin32. in openpyxl you have "style_names" and "named_styles" attributes, maybe they provide you with what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that does not answer to the question but can help solve the issue.

1. Setting a format in some given cells (for example in a worksheet called "STYLES")
2. Retrieving all the styles and registering them with `openpyxl`
3. Using the styles with their names

In **Excel**, that would give something like this:

[image: Styles defined in STYLES]

In **Python**, you can add the following function and call it:

```
from copy import copy
import logging
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
from typing import Dict

def _register_styles(wb:Workbook, ws_style: Worksheet) -> Dict[str, NamedStyle]:
    """Parse a column of cells and register the styles
    (the style names are the values of cells)

    Args:
        wb: The workbook
        ws_style: The worksheet with the styles defined

    Returns:
        Dictionary of styles, by names
    """
    list_styles = dict()  # type: Dict[str, NamedStyle]
    # Register styles of a config cells
    col, row = "A", 2
    cell = ws_style[col + str(row)]  # or in Python 3.6+: f"{col}{row}"
    while cell.value:
        style = NamedStyle(name=cell.value)
        style.font = copy(cell.font)
        style.fill = copy(cell.fill)
        style.border = copy(cell.border)
        style.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
        style.number_format = copy(cell.number_format)

        try:
            wb.add_named_style(style)
        except ValueError as e:
            logging.warning("W006: style creation skipped because {}".format(e))
        list_styles[cell.value] = style

        row += 1
        cell = ws_style[col + str(row)]  # or in Python 3.6+: f"{col}{row}"

    return list_styles


wb = load_workbook("My_Template.xlsx")
_register_styles(wb, wb["STYLES"])
```

*NOTE: if you use Python prior to version 3.4, just remove the type hints at the beginning of the function prototype:*
`def _register_styles(wb, ws_style):`